# Package VirtualBox executable with VM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a complex application that runs on a Linux distro that needs to be demonstrated to a customer using Windows. I am planning on walking them through installing VirtualBox and sending them an exported OVA appliance with my application running, then walking them through importing the OVA and booting-up the VM.

What would be better is if the customer didn't have to install VirtualBox or import the OVA. Does VirtualBox support creating a package that contains both a VirtualBox executable AND my OVA appliance? The idea being that the customer just clicks some `*.exe` sent by me and the Linux VM just boots up. Is this supported in any way using VirtualBox?

Comment: You might be able to do it with the Portable Apps version of virtualbox ..

Comment: What about doing screen sharing with the client? In my experience, asking client to do something technical will always end up in a headache.

Comment: @JakeGould thanks for the suggestion. I am supposed to train my client in how to use the application we are developing so they need to drive it, but I am trying to simplify the process where I can. If I can save them a few clicks, great, but if not, then they are able to do the developer's steps to get things going.

Comment: @rajb245 If I were you I would recommend purely doing remote interaction with others. What you are imagining as being simple actually opens a can of worms for you and the whole process. Save yourself the headache.

Comment: @JakeGould i appreciate your perspective and the experience that informs it. doing a purely remote interaction would not meet my contractual obligations to the customer.